# MS Word field code error - "Error! No text of specified style in document"

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007

I just opened a word document, in MS Word 2007, and the following error appears before the Figure and Table numbers:

Error! No text of specified style in document

The figure/table names code (after pressing alt-F9) looks like:

```
Table {STYLEREF 1\s},{SEQ Table\* ARABIC\s 1}
```

This error was not present when I worked on the file previously and I am the sole user of the file.

Why is this error occuring and what is the best way to troubleshoot/solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

{ STYLEREF 1 } is looking for a paragraph with the built-in style "Heading 1" (in English language versions of Word - if you are using another language version the heading styles may be named differently).

So if you don't have one of those, the { STYLEREF } field will flag the error you are seeing.

Comment: Thanks - therefore I can solve the problem by deleting {STYLEREF 1\s} altoghether

Comment: { STYLEREF 1 \s } just inserts the heading number from the preceding Heading 1 style, so if you do not have any Heading 1 style paragraphs, there would be no point having the STYLERF field. I guess the "," after it should also go.

Answer (score 1):

One other way to fix this is to insert a Heading 1 formatted line as hidden text. The error will disappear. I used "Hidden heading 1" so I would remember why it was there. Works on Word 2016.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same situation when creating a StyleRef link.  I eventually found out that the referred text was in a floating text box. As soon as I placed the text into the document on a regular line, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me after I opened an old word document in a new PC where my custom styles were loaded before the standard styles list. After struggling for some time, I created another custom Heading 1 using the standard Heading 1 and applied the same styles as my previous H1 styles. The caption worked fine after that.

Answer (score 0):

if your caption of figures or tables was referring to a heading number (chapter) , e.g Figure 1-2, meaning figure 2 in chapter 1, try the following;-

1. click insert caption
2. click on numbering,
3. uncheck "include chapter number"

After this  you should be able to add figures and tables without the errors. hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

If you have the error! no text of specified style in document."error in your captions (table and figure titles) it means that somehow the field properties "style name"box has been corrupted. So right click on the offending title.  Then select edit field.  Then look at the field properties box and select caption. Hit OK, and for once, it should be.